# Converting a text selection to subscript?

Tags: formatting

I have expressions with lots of variables which were typed quickly, like for example `vx`, `vy`, etc..., but now I wish to convert the important results to a nice formatting. It would be greatly convenient for me to select the `x` in `vx` and turn it into subscript, but, however the subscript tool in the typesetting palette just starts a subscript cursor for typing a new subscript.

Isn't it possible to convert some chars to subscript just like when you convert them to bold in a text editor?

Answer (score 3):

```
newvar[vx_] := Module[{var}, var = Characters[ToString[vx]];
               ToExpression[SubscriptBox[StringJoin[var[[1 ;; -2]]], var[[-1]]]]]

newvar[vx]
newvar[uvx]
```

> $\rm v_x$
>
> $\rm uv_x$

```
z = newvar[uvx]
```

$\rm uv_x$ =5 (*assign value to subscripted variable*)

```
z
```

> 5

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because it's certainly helpful, although I wished for a GUI-based format change. Finally I did the changes manually.